# How to add a function to web form submit button?

Tags: webforms

On a Drupal site, when a form submission is done. I need to **trigger a SMS**. I am unable to edit the form submit code. Please let me know how to add a function to webform submit button. So that on **SUBMIT** button click the **SMS function** get executed as well the form data goes to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Your mileage will vary, but it's the same as adding submit handlers to any form:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'foo') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'MYMODULE_some_function';
  }
}

function MYMODULE_some_function($form, &$form_state) {
  // Do something...
}
```

See [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) for full details.

Comment: But the problem with MYMODULE_form_alter function is the submissions will not get stored in the database.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand - you're adding an _extra_ submit handler, you're not replacing the existing one(s). Is that what you meant?

Comment: yes exactly.. on submit click i want both functions. Default form submit action as well as additional functionality of sending a SMS

Comment: Yep, that's _exactly_ what the above code does. Always best to check whether something works first before guessing that it won't

Comment: Previously i had seen the some answers on a question about the alert function. Thanks for the answer. Will they it out.

Comment: That would probably refer to the JS `alter()` function (PHP doesn't have a namesake). Good luck getting it sorted anyway